# Is it possible to interchange Azure Database for MySQL between general-purpose and memory-optimised?

Tags: mysql, azure, mysql8

I have one instance of [Azure Database for MySQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mysql/). The current configuration of the instance is "`Gen5 - General Purpose - 2 vCore - 10GBMem`".  I would like to scale it to "`Gen5 - Memory Optimised - 2 vCore - 20GBMem`". Since I am going to do this on a trial basis, I need to be able to scale it down to current configuration and do not want to get stuck in the "`Memory-optimized`" instance upgrade. I searched for documentation on this but unfortunately, I could not find anything effective and useful.

Please let me know if I can interchange between the two configurations.

Additional link for reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-pricing-tiers

Comment: What do you hope to gain?  How big is your dataset?  Are you running into performance problems?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to and from General Purpose and Memory Optimized is possible. See: [Scale Resources](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-pricing-tiers#scale-resources) for more information.

> After you create a server, the number of vCores, hardware generation, and pricing tier (except to and from Basic) can be changed up or down within seconds. You also can independently adjust the amount of storage up and the backup retention period up or down with no application downtime. You can't change the backup storage type after a server is created. For more information, see the Scale resources section.

Please le me know if you have additinal questions.